# Chrome reports a cookie as not Secure even though the Secure flag is set

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-chrome, iis-7

Our CMS Search is no longer working after this weekend's patch cycle. When we interrogate Chrome (*other browsers are return search results*) via Developer Tools we see these cookies flagged as having issues... but the description of the issue does not make sense because Secure is set to true AND SameSite is set to None.

[image]

It's difficult to know what to do here. I think getting Chrome to recognize that these cookies are configured correctly will solve our problem -- but I can't seem to figure out what is the problem?

In our web.config (CMS search was working up until Sunday):

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.8">
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" sameSite="None"/>
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

This is the KB that was installed on Sunday that we think caused our CMS search to stop working:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4576486/kb4576486

Thank you.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.

If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.

We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below iis URL rewrite rule:

```
<outboundRules>

  <clear />

  <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">

    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />

    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None; Secure" />

  </rule>

  <preConditions>

    <preCondition name="No SameSite">

      <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />

      <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None; Secure" negate="true" />

    </preCondition>

  </preConditions>

</outboundRules>
```

Reference link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1